# How to send objects from class to text file?

Tags: python, pandas

First I use pandas to create variables for different aggregates of data.  Then I create a class so that I can access those aggregates.  Once I create new objects from the class I want to send that data to a text file.  I'm able to send one of the instances from the class to the text file, but not all four come with it.  I'll try to put notes below to try and explain where its going wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as DT

onboard = df

#get variables from data

r1 = onboard['regions'] == "Northern Region (R1)"    
perm = onboard['perm_temp'] == "Perm"
temp = onboard['perm_temp'] == "Temp"
r1_perm = onboard[r1 & perm].ssno.count()
r1_temp = onboard[r1 & temp].ssno.count()
```

My class:

```
class Demographics(object):
'Common base class for demographics'

    #Create variables for tenure
    def __init__(self,perm, temp, endstrength, percent):

        self.perm = perm
        self.temp = temp        
        self.endstrength = endstrength
        self.percent = percent

    def displayDemo(self):

        return "Perm: %s" % self.perm
        return "Temp: %s" % self.temp
        return "Endstrength %s" % self.endstrength
        return "Percent %s" % self.percent
```

Now create my new object:

```
r1_demo = Demographics(r1_perm, r1_temp, r1_total, r1_percent)
```

send to .txt file

```
path1 = r'C:\Users\davidlopez\Desktop\region1.txt'
target = open(path1, 'w') 
target.write("\n")
target.write("region1:\n")
target.write(r1_demo.displayDemo())
target.close()
print "sent...."
```

So what comes across is only the first instance (think this is what its called) and my .txt file looks like this:

```
Perm:  3456
```

But it should look like:

```
Perm:  3456
Temp:  5677
Endstrength:  9133
Percent:  100.0
```

Furthermore, I'm wondering if theres a way to do a loop. So if I have 44 different regions, and all of them are callable, how do I loop through them from the class?

Comment: as @anti1869 pointed out, your use of `return` is wrong. remember that `return` exits the function, so any code after the first return will never be reached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoah! Easy with those `returns`

```
result = "Perm: %s" \
"Temp: %s" \
"Endstrength %s " \
"Percent %s" % (self.perm, self.temp, self.endstrength, self.percent)

return result
```

https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return_stmt

Comment: I'm still new to programming so I appreciate the response.  I didn't know about the return statements and your response is going to be extremely valuable to me.  Thanks.

Comment: the export from the answer above wont' allow me to print as integers.  For example if I change the %s to %5d, I receive an error.  How do I fix this?